# T-SQL (Cross?) Joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Code:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ID INT, Val1 VARCHAR(25), Val2 VARCHAR(25));
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (ID INT, Val3 BIT);
DECLARE @T3 TABLE (ID INT, Val4 DECIMAL(18,6));

INSERT INTO @T1 ( [ID], [Val1], [Val2] )
VALUES  ( 1, 'V1One','V2One' )
        ,(2, 'V1Two','V2Two' )
        ,(3, 'V1Three','V2Three' )
        ,(4, 'V1Four','V2Four' );

INSERT INTO @T2 ( [ID], [Val3] )
VALUES  ( 3, 1 );

INSERT INTO @T3 ( [ID], [Val4] )
VALUES  ( 4, 9.99 )
        ,( 5, 0.99 );
```

Desired Output:

```
ID  Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4
1   V1One   V2One   NULL    NULL
2   V1Two   V2Two   NULL    NULL
3   V1Three V2Three 1       NULL
4   V1Four  V2Four  NULL    9.990000
5   NULL    NULL    NULL    0.99
```

Goal:

> To combine three tables based on [ID] field ("key column") and create
>   the desired output.  If a record exists in only two tables, return
>   NULL for the other table's field(s) - i.e. ID = 3 and 4 If a record
>   exists in one table but not other, return NULL for the other tables'
>   field(s) - i.e. ID = 1, 2, and 5
>
> The query has to perform fast as the real data-set is quite huge and
>   much more complex.

My try so far..

```
SELECT COALESCE([T1].[ID],[T2].[ID],[T3].[ID]), Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4 
FROM @T1 T1
CROSS JOIN @T2 T2 
CROSS JOIN @T3 T3
--WHERE T1.[ID] = T2.[ID]
--WHERE T1.[ID] = T3.[ID]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want FULL join, rather than CROSS join.

```
SELECT COALESCE([T1].[ID],[T2].[ID],[T3].[ID]), Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4 
FROM T1 T1
FULL JOIN @T2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
FULL JOIN @T3 T3 ON T3.ID = COALESCE(T1.ID, T2.ID)
```

Comment: You can use left join instead of CROSS join

Comment: But not for this query :) LEFT join would not be able to add ID 5 from T3.

Comment: Perfecto! Gracias amigo~