# SQL insert values from a query with calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table like this:

```
id type | month | value
```

Where type is `AC`,`FC` or `BG`

I want to create for each distinct row id,type(where type is `AC` or `FC`) a new row with type `AF` and value as `AC` if exist or as `FC` (`AC` value has priority on `FC` value).

For the moment I can extract unique list on which for each item I have to create a new row:

```
select id_prj,month  from table where type='AC' or type='FC' group by id_prj,month
```

How do I create for each item returned from this query a new row with the value that can assume AC or FC value depending on its existence.

Below a table example

```
| ID_PRJ | TYPE | MONTH | VALUE |
-----------------------------
| 1  | AC   |  1    | 1000  |
-----------------------------
| 1  | FC   |  1    | 200  |
-----------------------------
| 3  | BG   |  1    | 1000  |
-----------------------------
| 4  | FC   |  2    | 100  |
```

The table after the insert should be:

```
| ID_PRJ | TYPE | MONTH | VALUE |
-----------------------------
| 1  | AC   |  1    | 1000  |
-----------------------------
| 1  | FC   |  1    | 200  |
-----------------------------
| 3  | BG   |  1    | 1000  |
-----------------------------
| 4  | FC   |  2    | 100  |
-----------------------------
| 1  | AF   |  1    | 1000  |
-----------------------------
| 4  | AF   |  2    | 100  |
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for in the output. Can you add a bit more detail? An example of the output you are getting now vs what you are looking for would be great.

Comment: the output is id and month and for each id and month i want to create a new row with the id,month,type='AF',value='the value of the row where id='ID' where type is AC fi exist or type is FC

Comment: a new row or column? and you need to provide a table of data and what the data should look like, in a table format, afterwards. Here's a recent question where they do that... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143148/t-sql-cross-joins

Comment: Edited the quesiton with origal table and the table I wish to produce. I want a new row not a new column.

Comment: In the first table shouldn't it be `2` in the month at row 4?

Comment: Yes you are right. I changed the example modifying row 4 of original table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this :

```
insert into table (ID_PRJ, TYPE, Month, Value)


select id_prj,type,month,value from (
select id_prj,'FC' as type, month,value  , row_number() over ( partition by id_prj order by type asc) rowid
from table 
where type='AC' or type='FC' 
) as x where rowid = 1
```

Comment: it's not clear to me. Can you explain the logic behind? I don't kno what partition and whic FC as type

Comment: Thi query has a problem. Since for the same id we can have 12 rows for type AC and 12 for type FC it will create just one row for each id due to partion and rowid 1. I want to produce 12 rows not just one.

Comment: Maybe I can add ,month to partition by in order to separate the rows for id and month.
select id,type,month,value from (
select id,'AF' as type, month,value  , row_number() over ( partition by id,month order by type asc) rowid
from ppm.dbo.monthly_financials 
where type='AC' or type='FC' 
) as x where rowid = 1

Comment: this should work for the sample data you provided, but you could add month and value to the partition by.

Comment: Yes i added month to partition by and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to just be changing the type. I think this does it.

```
insert into table (ID_PRJ, TYPE, Month, Value)
Select ID_PRJ, 'AF' Type, Month, Value
from table where Type in ('AC','FC')
```

Comment: in case there are 2 rows for AC and FC it will produce two rows but i want just one with the value of type=AC and if not exist with type=AC i want the value from type=FC

Comment: In that case, Kostya has the right solution. His query using partition numbers each id_prj looking at only AC or FC records and orders them by type, meaning AC before FC, if they exist and then he takes the value from the top one to create your record.

Answer (score 1):

One fairly simple way to do it is to use a full join to a derived table.

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ID_PRJ int,
    TYPE char(2),
    MONTH int,
    VALUE int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 'AC', 1, 1000),
(1, 'FC', 1, 200),
(3, 'BG', 1, 1000),
(4, 'FC', 2, 100)
```

The insert...select statement:

```
INSERT INTO @T (ID_PRJ, MONTH, TYPE, VALUE)
SELECT  ISNULL(t1.ID_PRJ, t0.ID_PRJ), 
        ISNULL(t1.MONTH, t0.MONTH), 
        'AF', 
        ISNULL(t1.VALUE, t0.VALUE)
FROM @T t0
FULL JOIN
(
    SELECT ID_PRJ, MONTH, TYPE, VALUE
    FROM @T 
    WHERE TYPE = 'AC'
) t1 ON t0.ID_PRJ = t1.ID_PRJ
    AND t0.MONTH = t1.MONTH
WHERE t0.TYPE IS NULL OR t0.TYPE = 'FC'
```

Verify insert:

```
SELECT ID_PRJ, MONTH, TYPE, VALUE
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
ID_PRJ  MONTH   TYPE    VALUE
1       1       AC      1000
1       1       FC      200
3       1       BG      1000
4       2       FC      100
1       1       AF      1000
4       2       AF      100
```